# Element by element formulae for 3x3 matrix inversion

Tags: matrices

Given a 3 x 3 matrix:

$$
       A= \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b & c \\
        d & e & f \\
        g & h & i \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Can $A^{-1}$ be shown as as a 3x3 matrix with each element in terms of $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$ and $i$. Showing  basic operators (only $+ - / *$)?

Comment: see [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_matrix#Inversion_of_3.C3.973_matrices]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det(A)} adj(A)$$

$$\det(A)=aei+dhc+bfg-ceg-bdi-afh$$

$$adj(A)= \begin{bmatrix}
        ei-fh & ch-bi & bf-ce \\
        fg-di & ai-cg & dc-af \\
        dh-ge & bg-ah  & ae-bd \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

_

Comment: +1 Nice one @N.S.